# Keycloak: is it possible to get values from a user attribute?

Tags: keycloak

I have an external database that my keycloak is using. This database is holding roles for users. I ended up getting these roles from the database and create a user attribute that holds this list (with other values):

[image]

I would like to add the given roles in the JWT token:

[image]

Is there any way to make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it have to be under the roles claim, or could it be added to another claim?

Comment: Should be there you can see in the picture.

Comment: So you want one role per line, that will be a bit tougher